# Why is not the code working for Python dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a dictionary below. I need to print the year and name who got rank 1

```
 ranklist = { 2000 : {1: ' Sara'  , 3 : 'Saj' , 2 : 'Pap' } , 
          2001 : {2: ' Sara'  , 1 : 'Saj' , 2 : 'Pap' } ,
          2002 : {3: ' Sara'  , 2 : 'Saj' , 1 : 'Pap' } ,
         }


a=[]
for year in ranklist:   
    out = {i: [] for i in ranklist}
    for rank in ranklist[year] :
        if rank == 1:
            #a.append(ranklist[year][rank])    
            out[year] = a.append(ranklist[year][rank])
```

out

```
{2000: [], 2001: [], 2002: None}
```

Expected out

```
{2000: 'Sara', 2001: Saj, 2002: 'Pap'}
```

Comment: `a.append(..)` does *not* return a new list, it returns `None`.

Comment: ...and `out` variable is getting rewritten each iteration

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two errors here:

1. you each time "reset" your `out` in the outer `for` loop; and
2. `.append(..)` returns `None`, not a new list.

You can however rewrite the above to:

```
out = { k: v.get(1) for k, v in ranklist.items() }
```

So here we take for each key-value pair the key and map it to the value in the corresponding dictionary with `1` as key.

Or if you want to omit subdictionaries without a key `1`:

```
out = { k: v.get(1) for k, v in ranklist.items() if 1 in v }
```

Comment: my oyut is like this {2000: ' Sara', 2001: 'Saj', 2002: None}, why 2002 printing None

Comment: @user1875458: as said, because `.append(..)` returns `None`, it changes the list, it does not return (a copy of) the list.

Answer (score 2):

This should solve it:

```py
result = {k: v.get(1) for k, v in ranklist.items()}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your doing a couple things wrong. There is no need for `out` if you want to store your results in `a`. You also keep overwriting `out`. There is no need to iterate through the dictionary, that is one of its advantages; so just get the key. Also, append returns `None` and that is not what you want. And you can do this in one line:

```
a={i:ranklist[i][1] for i in ranklist}
print(a)
```

Output:

```
{2000: ' Sara', 2001: 'Saj', 2002: 'Pap'}
```

Answer (score 0):

What would be better is just return a dictionary with the year as the key and the name of the best performer as the value.

```
a = {}
for year in ranklist:
    a[year] = ranklist[year][1]
```